# Mistake in proof Buck's Advanced Calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I do not understand the very last equality before the arrow. It seems to pop up out of nowhere. Below I copy the proof in its entirety.
This is from Buck's Advanced Calculus text pg. 46. Perhaps, this is a silly misunderstanding, but to me it doesn't seem to follow from the rest of the proof.

$ \it \bf Lemma: $

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{ \log n}{n})  = 0$$

$ \it \bf Proof: $ 
Given $n$, choose $ k $ so that $(k-1)^2 \leq n < k^2$.
It is easily checked that the inequality $k^2 < 2^{k-1}$ holds for all $k \geq 7$. Thus, for any $n \geq (6)^2 = 36$, we have

$$ \log n \leq \log(k^2) < \log(2^{k-1}) = (k-1) \log 2 \leq  \sqrt{n} \log 2  $$
and we have shown that $$ \frac{ \log n}{n} \leq \frac{ \sqrt{n}\log 2}{n} = \frac{ \log 2}{\sqrt{n}}  \rightarrow 0$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for $n\in \mathbb{R}^+$ you can write $n = \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}$, then

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}\log(2)}{n} = \frac{\sqrt{n}\log(2)}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\log(2)}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: That definitely explains it. I'll accept when it allows. I guess, it's just the seemingly contrived nature of this proof, that makes it "confusing". I'm not very well practiced in analysis. I'm using this book to learn multivariable calculus, but it's proving to be challenging to even get to the meat of the subject, as it were.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}?$$